# How To develop paytm login page text box placeholder effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

How To develop paytm login page text box placeholder effect?

[image]

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xituroguji/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

This is done purely using CSS3 transitions.

> Reference article : http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-material-design-floating-input-placeholder/

**HTML CODE:**

```
<input placeholder="Username" type="text" required>
<input placeholder="Password" type="password" required>
```

**CSS3:**

```
input {
 margin: 40px 25px;
 width: 200px;
 display: block;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 0;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #1abc9c;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
 transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #1abc9c 4%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #1abc9c 4%);
 background-position: -200px 0;
 background-size: 200px 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 color: #0e6252;
}

input:focus,
  input:valid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
  input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #1abc9c;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a1kvcn6/1/)

Comment: it hides place holder after add text. Any solution for that.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot : I am not quite sure if i have understood what you meant , could you be more specific , if possible share  a example of  your issue

Comment: The same example given in live demo. When you focus placeholder float to up . when you write it hide, I want to keep that place holder.

Comment: you mean like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/2a1kvcn6/10/

Answer (score 0):

Html5 `input` has a `placeholder` attribute, just set that to the text, you want shown when the input is empty.

You can read more about and try it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: That doesn't explain how to do the transition, see the other answer.